# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Handling ServiceScope usage with dependencies on WebSocket middleware's every incoming messages

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, middleware, azure-web-app-service

I have some performance issue on using websockets on ASP.NET Core 2.1

At first, I have an implementation of websockets similar to this example:
https://radu-matei.com/blog/aspnet-core-websockets-middleware/

On every incoming websocket message, I have it to parse, call some services, send a message back to websocket.

```
if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
{
   using (var scope = service.CreateScope())
   {
      var communicationService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetSomeService(); 
      await communicationService.HandleConnection(webSocket, result, buffer);
   }
}
```

So as you see on every incoming message I am creating a new Scope, getting Service provider and then calling services on this service's method communicationService.HandleConnection. But if there is a lot of messages, my Azure WebService CPU goes up to 100%.
Can someone tell me if I am using these scope creations correct on every socket message?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for certain with the limited code snippet you provided (i.e. the lifetime and type of `communicationService`. Having said that, I would look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-availability-performance-application-issues to capture a snapshot of your app service when the CPU spike to 100%. You may discover the issue might be unrelated to your `using (scope)`.